# Hotkey to switch between tabs in developer console

Tags: developer-console

I thought this could be very useful. Very often I find myself looking for something in other browser tabs that indeed sits in one of the developer console tabs! Probably this wouldn't solve this issue but having keyboard shortcut to switch between tabs would save some mouse movement.

I know there is something `Navigate backward through the open views CTRL+PAGE UP` which does not seem to work.

I'd love to map these to BetterTouchTool for TipTap trackpad gesture (or your fancy mouse) as I already do with browser.

Any input appreciated.

If there isn't one - I will submit one to Salesforce Ideas. Also, one could probably hack something up with Greasemonkey!

**EDIT**: Developer console has this built in! It's control + page Up/Down. Too bad it's built into Chrome which is causing a conflict. Extensions Hotkey and Shortcut Manager did not help.

**Update**: It works on Mac Safari & Chrome. Use Fn + Command + Up / Down arrows. So it seems it's only Windows Chrome issue.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are ONLY following shortcuts available in developer console: 
[image: shortcut keys]

So you will need to post an idea and wait till SFDC provide this feature.

Comment: Probably I will, but I did have a look into Developer Console source code. I think it's possible to reverse engineer it. The tab button is `<button id="tab-1189-btnEl">`, the next id is tab-1201, etc. so you probably could sort them to get the switching direction. Now there is a JS function called setActiveTab. The trouble is the JS library weighs 1.2mb (minified) and it crashes my office browser when trying to beautify it :) also I am not great with Firebug yet.

Comment: I agree technically its possible. But I don't think this feature is worth that much efforts. Also event if you home how manage to hack the JS then also SFDC can change it at any time and your code may break again.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why CTRL+PAGE UP doesn't work for you. Are you using a mac? I would file a bug with Salesforce as it doesn't sound like that key mapping is platform/browser compatible.

As a workaround (hack, since as ArulRajguru9 mentioned this might break between releases), I wrote an example that can be used as a bookmarklet, or converted to a greasemonkey script if that is what you like to use. It could also be easily used as a chrome extension to be loaded ever time the dev console loads. I'm assuming from this example, you can hook it up to your BetterTouchTool.

Happy hacking.

```
(function() {
   var editors = Ext.getCmp('editors');
   function useNumbersToActivateTabs(code, evt) { 
      var index = code - Ext.EventObject.ONE;
      var editor = editors.items.get(index);

      if (editor) editors.setActiveTab(index);
   }
   var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
      fn : useNumbersToActivateTabs,
      key : "123456789", 
      ctrl : true, 
      target : document
   });

   /* replace with the keys you want */
   var scrollBackKey = 219; /* [ */
   var scrollForwardKey = 221; /* ] */

   function scrollThroughTabs(code, evt) {
      var editor = editors.getActiveTab();
      var index = editors.items.indexOf(editor);
      var newIndex = 0;
      if (code === scrollBackKey) {
         newIndex = index - 1;
         if (newIndex < 0) newIndex = editors.items.length - 1;
      } else if (code === scrollForwardKey) {
         newIndex = index + 1; 
         if (newIndex >= editors.items.length) newIndex = 0;
      }
      if (editors.items.length > 0) editors.setActiveTab(newIndex);
   }

   var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
      fn : scrollThroughTabs,
      key : [scrollBackKey, scrollForwardKey],
      /* Choose if you want ctrl or shift. ctrl here will be automatically cmd on mac */
      ctrl : true,
      shift : true,
      target : document
   });
})()
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I am using my Mac, but tried ctrl+page up on my office box (Windows 7) too. I am using Chrome so that just switches the Chrome tabs. It's a built in keyboard shortcut in Chrome (although not documented in the official shortcuts page): http://gappstips.com/chrome-tips/view/84/handy-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-chrome

Comment: Ahh, so that plugin is overriding page up/down? In any case, let me know if that script works for you or need more instructions to get it to work.

Comment: No. Plugin does nothing. ctrl+page up/down is chrome's built in hotkey! Tab switching with these does work with Firefox! Basically it's a conflict. Wondering if I can customize Chrome for this.